# DISTINCT WHERE query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to put a where clause in a select distinct query in postgresql but having no luck.

I want to do the following:

```
select distinct on (state_or_county) state_or_county 
from locations 
where country = "USA"
```

I've done this many times in mysql and can't understand why this isn't working.

Can someone please correct the query? Or explain just why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgresql a string literal must be wrapped in single quotes:

```
select distinct on (state_or_county) state_or_county 
from locations 
where country = 'USA'
```

Double quotes are used for identifiers, if needed:

```
select distinct on ("state_or_county") "state_or_county" 
from "locations" 
where "country" = 'USA'
```

Comment: Note this is how the SQL spec says to do things.  Yet again, MySQL's tendency to go off mission in regards to the SQL spec means it does things just a little bit different than you might expect, and results in users learning bad habits when they switch to another db that does follow the rules.