# unable to use a select clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here is a very interesting problem I found.

Here is a snapshot of my table
[majorversions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jg4q.png)

Now I try to execute a simple select statement

```
select * from majorversions mav
where mav.name = "Default-Media"
```

It throws an error

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "Default-Media" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 53
```

It is happening mainly due to the fact that name columnType is Text, if I user client_id in where clause everything works fine.

So how to write a where clause with name as the Column?

Comment: Use single quotes for a string, like `'Default-Media'`.  Double quotes refer to a column called Default-Media.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DISTINCT WHERE query in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480102/distinct-where-query-in-postgresql)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for strings.
If it's encased in double quotes it'll think it's a column name and it can't find that column. Thats why you're getting that error.

It should be:

```
select * from majorversions mav
where mav.name = 'Default-Media'
```

What it tries to execute in your query is:

```
select * from majorversions mav where mav.name = mav.Default-Media
```

Answer (score 0):

Default-Media should be written `'Default-Media'` and not `"Default-Media"`